# SQL Server unique column value across other columns (in other table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008.  I have the following basic schema:

- `Table1` (`Field1, Field2`)
- `Table2` (`Field3`)

I need `Field1` to be unique (nulls allowed). I can do this with something like:

```
create unique nonclustered index IX_Table1_Field1 
on [Table1] (Field1)
where Field1 is not null
```

However, I also need `Field1` to be unique across `Field2` and `Field3`. i.e. if the value I want to use in `Field1` is being used in `Field1, Field2`, or `Field3` then it cannot be allowed.

Is this possible with an index? (how can I achieve this?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Unique constraint across multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337944/sql-unique-constraint-across-multiple-tables)

Comment: If the "domain" of values that can appear in `Field1` is the same as the domain of values that can appear in `Field2` and in `Field3`, it suggests that the table design is wrong and there ought to only be a single column containing these values (and possibly one or more additional columns that distinguish other characteristics)

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way of doing this without rearranging the tables or using a trigger.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson if you know how to do this with a trigger I'm open to suggested answers via other means. Thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is a good point.  I will have to check the full usages of "Field2" and "Field3" and see if they arent really the same thing...

Comment: @nashwan I think you should consider the other option first, a trigger solution is possible, but not exactly straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a faulty design, to be honest.  While what you're talking about could theoretically be achieved with triggers, the fact that you have such an unusual constraint suggests that the tables may not be modeled correctly.

Perhaps if you explained what the two tables and three fields represent, we could better understand how you arrived at this design and might be able to suggest alternatives.

Something to consider: although you only mentioned a limitation on `Field1`, usually a multi-field constraint involves all the fields.  Is `Field2` limited by fields 1, 2, and 3 as well?  What about `Field3`?  Are there any restrictions on how records can be changed or deleted?