# Insert n rows stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Trying to insert multiple rows based on a passed parameter.

Tried this and it only repeated once:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ActivateCertificates]

    @Count              int,
    @CertificateNumber  int,
    @Buyer              VarChar(50)


AS
Declare @x int
Declare @InitialCharacter   Char(1)
SET @InitialCharacter='C'
Declare @Last3      Char(3)
SET @Last3='867'

    while @x <= @Count 
begin
    /* CREATE THE CERTIFICATE NUMBER */
    set @CertificateNumber = @CertificateNumber +1
    /* insert into certificates  cert number and who sold to. */
    INSERT into Certificates (CertificateNumber,Buyer) 
    VALUES (@InitialCharacter + ltrim(rtrim(cast(@CertificateNumber as char))) + @Last3, @Buyer) 
end 
set @x =@x + 1


GO
```

Comment: Initialize @x to 0; increment it inside the begin..end block.

Comment: Don't write loops in TSQL. Write a set based query to do that instead.

Comment: Thanks, Got that working, how would i return an error message if one of the inserts tried to insert a cert number that already existed as this is a unique value in the DB

Comment: Ok, I will start using set based query, can you show me the differance??

Comment: Of greater concern to me than your use of loops is your CertificateNumber, which seems to be one of those legacy critters that have embedded meaning. Does that three-digit suffix have significance? And why are you trimming @CertificateNumber?  It is passed an integer. When you cast it to char it shouldn't accrete any spaces.

Comment: `how would i return an error message if one of the inserts tried to insert a cert number that already existed as this is a unique value in the DB` Is there a unique index on CertificateNumber column in the table?

Comment: CertificateNumber is a column in the table

Comment: three-digit suffix static for first million records @CertificateNumber passed as integer so it can increment by 1

Comment: Static initial character + @CertificateNumber + three-digit suffix inserted into dB Character field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal using a set-based query instead of a loop (*BTW there are lots of such examples here on StackOverflow*) you'll have to have a tally (numbers) table or create it on a fly with a subquery or recursive CTE.

```
CREATE TABLE tally (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

To populate it up to 100000 ([Celko-style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338831/1920232))

```
INSERT INTO tally (id) 
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + d.N * 1000 + e.N * 10000 + 1 as N
  FROM (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) e
ORDER BY N;
```

Now your stored procedure boils down to one statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActivateCertificates
  @Count              INT,
  @CertificateNumber  INT,
  @Buyer              VARCHAR(50)
AS
INSERT INTO Certificates (CertificateNumber, Buyer) 
SELECT 'C' + CAST(q.number + t.id AS VARCHAR(12)) + '867', q.buyer 
  FROM
( 
  SELECT @CertificateNumber number, @Buyer buyer
) q, tally t
WHERE t.id <= @Count;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fb24/1)** demo

**Now if you generate relatively small amounts of certificates** (< 32768) then you can use recursive CTE to build a sequence of numbers (and don't need a persisted tally table)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActivateCertificates
  @Count              INT,
  @CertificateNumber  INT,
  @Buyer              VARCHAR(50)
AS
WITH tally AS (
  SELECT 1 id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id + 1 FROM tally WHERE id < @Count
)
INSERT INTO Certificates (CertificateNumber, Buyer) 
SELECT 'C' + CAST(q.number + t.id AS VARCHAR(12)) + '867', q.buyer 
  FROM
( 
  SELECT @CertificateNumber number, @Buyer buyer
) q, tally t OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ca84/2)** demo for that case

Comment: Excellent alternative but I still have on burning question.....I got it to work the way I wanted using a variation of my original idea, what are the advantages of your way?

Comment: @DougFarrell Good for you. RDBMSes are optimized to work with sets so thats more efficient. You can take a look at some comparison (loops vs. sets) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17139749/1920232.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it I will definitely use this method next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is incremented outside the `BEGIN/END` block. Also I would recommend you initially set your variable to 0 to avoid any potential garbage data stored in that memory location.

Comment: Got that figured out, couldn't answer my own Q as this is my first day here. What do you think about the above comment to use a set based query instead? Can anyone show me one vs the one i wrote above?