# How to add unique constraint to columns across tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Say I have two columns: `GroupName` in one table, and `Username` in another. How do I constrain the values of these columns so that any value added to one column **is unique across both columns**? Preferably in a "non-messy" way.

Comment: Make both columns as unique key

Comment: @KedarLimaye They are not in the same table

Comment: share the input sample first and what you want to get as desired output sample

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337944/sql-unique-constraint-across-multiple-tables

Comment: @KedarLimaye not what I was hoping for, but it is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Sample data would help clarify exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way with the structure that you mention.  Of course, there *is* a way by implementing triggers, but that is cumbersome.

An alternative data model fixes the problem, though:

```
create table things (
    thingsId int auto_increment primary key,
    name text,
    type text,
    . . .
    check (type in ('group', 'user')),
    unique (name)
);
```

This puts each type of thing into a single column and then imposes the unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using triggers and `SELECT RAISE(FAIL, ...)`:

For example, suppose I have a `Shelf` Table and I want it to contain `Book`s and `Magazine`s. I also don't want a `Book` and a `Magazine` to have the same title on a shelf. I'd really like a unique constraint on `(Shelf.ShelfID, Book.BookID OR Magazine.MagazineID)`, but the language doesn't offer that. Let's:

Create the tables (NOTE: in a real world implementation, the docs recommend [indexes on foreign keys](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) for performance):

You can run all the following conveniently with:

```bash
sqlite3 -echo :memory: < ./run.sql
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Shelf (
    ShelfID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(Title)
) STRICT;

CREATE TABLE Book (
    BookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShelfID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ShelfID) REFERENCES Shelf(ShelfID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE(Title)
) STRICT;

CREATE TABLE Magazine (
    MagazineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShelfID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ShelfID) REFERENCES Shelf(ShelfID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE(Title)
) STRICT;
```

Create the view and the triggers (this is the magic bit):

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_Book_Magazine_Shelf_AllTitles AS
SELECT s.ShelfID, b.Title
FROM Shelf s JOIN Book b ON s.ShelfID = b.ShelfID
UNION ALL
SELECT s.ShelfID, m.Title
FROM Shelf s JOIN Magazine m ON s.ShelfID = m.ShelfID
;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_Book_Insert_CheckUniqueTitle
BEFORE INSERT ON Book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'title already exists in Shelf')
    FROM vw_Book_Magazine_Shelf_AllTitles
    WHERE ShelfID = NEW.ShelfID AND Title = NEW.Title;
END;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_Book_Update_CheckUniqueTitle
BEFORE UPDATE ON Book
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'title already exists in Shelf')
    FROM vw_Book_Magazine_Shelf_AllTitles
    WHERE ShelfID = NEW.ShelfID AND Title = NEW.Title;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_Magazine_Insert_CheckUniqueTitle
BEFORE INSERT ON Magazine
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'title already exists in Shelf')
    FROM vw_Book_Magazine_Shelf_AllTitles
    WHERE ShelfID = NEW.ShelfID AND Title = NEW.Title;
END;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_Magazine_Update_CheckUniqueTitle
BEFORE UPDATE ON Magazine
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'title already exists in Shelf')
    FROM vw_Book_Magazine_Shelf_AllTitles
    WHERE ShelfID = NEW.ShelfID AND Title = NEW.Title;
END;
```

And finally, let's test it:

```sql
INSERT INTO Shelf(ShelfID, Title) Values(1, 'Shelf Title');
INSERT INTO Book(BookID, ShelfID, Title) VALUES (1, 1, 'Book Title');
INSERT INTO Magazine(MagazineID, ShelfID, Title) VALUES (1, 1, 'Mag Title');
-- this fails
UPDATE Magazine SET Title = 'Book Title' WHERE Title = 'Mag Title';
```